# History replaceState problem in AJAXified Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, html5-history

I made an [Ajax enabled Wordpress theme](https://github.com/geraldo/places) with the main feature that internal links are not reloading the whole page but only the new content. So when URL's hash is changed, the new content is put in the #primary section and the map in the background stays untouched:

```
var $mainContent = $("#primary")

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    url = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    url = url + " #content"; 

    $mainContent.animate({opacity: "0.1"}).html('&lt;p&gt;Please wait...&lt;/&gt;').load(url, function() {
        $mainContent.animate({opacity: "1"});
    });
});
```

Everything works fine, also history back and forward navigation. You can check out the basic funcionality [here](https://github.com/geraldo/places).

Now I want nice URLs hiding the hashes, so for example a link like http://geraldkogler.com/places/#/places/place/stwst/ gets changed to http://geraldkogler.com/places/place/stwst/. I do this adding this code to line 47 of [ajax.js](https://github.com/geraldo/places/blob/master/js/ajax.js):

```
var oPageInfo = {
    title: "places",
    url: window.location.origin+window.location.hash.substring(1)
}   
window.history.replaceState(oPageInfo, oPageInfo.title, oPageInfo.url);
```

Now the URL gets rewritten - but history doesn't work any more.

So I think I should listen to popstate events, I try to do the following and so back works once, but not more:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
        var host = "http://"+location.hostname;
        location.hash = event.state.url.substring(host.length);
    }
};
```

This (wrong) behaviour with the mentioned code is shown on [this page](http://geraldkogler.com/places2). Any idea what I'm doing wrong in [ajax.js](http://geraldkogler.com/places2/wp-content/themes/places2/js/ajax.js?ver=5.3)?

Comment: `replaceState` replaces the current history entry if you want to keep previous ones use `pushState` instead

Comment: I know, that's why I'm using `replaceState` as I only want to substitutes de url with hash. `pushState` doubles the entry and back reloads the same page.